# How to convert this for loop into an apply function?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, sapply

I'm quite new to R and am currently studying a Monte Carlo Simulation example I found online, however it is given in a for loop. I would like to move away from these but am struggling to convert it into an apply function. Any help would be appreciated:

```
for (k in 1:1000)
    {
       rolls = runif(1,3000,5000)
       bags = runif(1,2000,4000)
       cases = runif(1,150,200)*30
       total = min (rolls, bags, cases)
       results = rbind(results, data.frame(rolls, bags, cases, total))
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `for` loop, nor any `apply` function.

`runif` can generate multiple `n` numbers in one go. To get rowwise minimum you can use `pmin`.

```
n <- 1000
rolls = runif(n,3000,5000)
bags = runif(n,2000,4000)
cases = runif(n,150,200)*30
total = pmin(rolls, bags, cases)
results <- data.frame(rolls, bags, cases, total)
```

---

As @Roland points out for a general case where you can't vectorize the simulation you can use `replicate` function.

```
simulation <- function() {
    rolls = runif(1,3000,5000)
    bags = runif(1,2000,4000)
    cases = runif(1,150,200)*30
    total = min(rolls, bags, cases)
    data.frame(rolls, bags, cases, total)
}

results <- t(replicate(1000, simulation(), simplify = TRUE))
```

Comment: But if your simulation can't be vectorized, R offers the `replicate` function, which would be used for this.